# Difficulty Quickloading :CL21 System with Quicklisp on Windows

Tags: gcc, common-lisp, quicklisp

The following error occurs during ql:quickload in SBCL

```
> * (ql:quickload :cl21) To load "cl21":   Load 1 ASDF system:
>     cl21 ; Loading "cl21" .....; gcc -m64 -o "C:\Users\davyp\AppData\Local\cache\common-lisp\sbcl-1.4.14-win-x64\C\Users\davyp\AppData\Local\lxss\root\quicklisp\dists\quicklisp\software\osicat-20160825-git\posix\basic-unixint__grovel-tmpGHU3ALSV.exe"
> -IC:/Users/davyp/AppData/Local/lxss/root/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/cffi_0.18.0/
> "C:\Users\davyp\AppData\Local\cache\common-lisp\sbcl-1.4.14-win-x64\C\Users\davyp\AppData\Local\lxss\root\quicklisp\dists\quicklisp\software\osicat-20160825-git\posix\basic-unixint__grovel.c"
> 
> debugger invoked on a CFFI-GROVEL:GROVEL-ERROR in thread #<THREAD
> "main thread" RUNNING {10012E0613}>: Couldn't execute "gcc": The
> system cannot find the file specified.
```

Initially I thought my Cygwin installation was out of date, but reinstalling & updating Cygwin has had no effect on the error. Thanks for any insights.

Comment: Is `gcc` in your path (does `gcc -v` from the same console work)?

Comment: @jkiiski, Problem oversight fixed, see below. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I forgot to execute `(ql-dist:install-dist "http://dists.cl21.org/cl21.txt")` before quickloading. Works fine now.